# SSRS 2014 URL access always generates XLS instead of XLSX when format is EXCEL

Tags: excel, reporting-services, sql-server-2014

I have SQL Server 2014 and I'm trying to access my reports via the URL access. As I understand, the Excel format should be giving me an XLSX file which supports an unlimited number of rows. However, after looking at my log files I noticed that I was getting maximum row errors for any reports with more then 65536 rows. After looking into this I discovered that any time I request the reports via URL with format as EXCEL, they generate a XLS file instead of XLSX. If I run the reports out of Visual Studio and export as EXCEL, they generate just fine as XLSX. Anyone have any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found the solution to this problem so I figured I'd answer it here in case anyone else runs into this problem. the list of supported formats for URL access listed on Microsoft's website [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms154040.aspx) shows the following list: HTML4.0, MHTML, IMAGE, EXCEL, WORD, CSV, PDF, XML, and NULL

It does not, however, list the one that actually generates an XLSX file. That format is **EXCELOPENXML**. Why they don't list this format is beyond me. Perhaps I was looking in the wrong places.

Comment: This is a life saver! I would give you one hundred up votes if I could. Thanks for sharing!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I know it's a very old thread, but I just had to deal with the very same problem on a legacy system we have.

I would like to confirm, @haymez's answer is right and add that documentation is a little bit better nowadays:

> The following XML shows the elements for the two Excel rendering extensions in the RSReportServer and RSReportDesigner configuration files:

```
<Extension Name="EXCELOPENXML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer.ExcelOpenXmlRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering"/>

<Extension Name="EXCEL" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.ExcelRenderer.ExcelRenderer,Microsoft.ReportingServices.ExcelRendering" Visible="false"/>
```

> The EXCELOPENXML extension defines the Excel renderer for current (.xlsx) Excel files. The EXCEL extension defines the Excel 2003 version. Visible = "false" indicates the Excel 2003 renderer is hidden. For more information, see

[Differences Between the current (.xlsx) Excel and Excel 2003 Renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-builder/exporting-to-microsoft-excel-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2016#differences-between-the-current-xlsx-excel-and-excel-2003-renderers)