# RDLC Report Downloading

Tags: c#, sql-server, ms-office, visual-studio-2019, rdlc

I have a project where we use downloads from reports which are made from the RDLC report designer(data taken from SQL Server). These downloads are in Word/Excel(97-2003) version. And If we open them from newer versions some alignments, spaces are changed. Can we change this download version from RDLC as Word/Excel versions(16-365)?

Comment: Possibly dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30195268/ssrs-2014-url-access-always-generates-xls-instead-of-xlsx-when-format-is-excel

Comment: @james that is in SQL server reporting, I need an idea regarding RDLC

Comment: Although RDLC runs in the client-side ReportViewer control, the ReportViewer control is still taking its export configuration from the RSReportServer.config file, so you can configure which formats and versions are available from there. If yours is still outputting Word/Excel 97-2003 versions, though, it sounds like you're on a quite old version of SQL Server and SSRS.